# CoffeeScript error different to to actual code

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

When I try to run. a coffeescript test I get this error:

```
/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/test/credentials.spec.coffee:366
  return creds = new AWS.TemporaryCredentials({
                 ^

TypeError: AWS.TemporaryCredentials is not a constructor
at setupCreds (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/test/credentials.spec.coffee:366:22)
at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/test/credentials.spec.coffee:399:7)
at Object.create (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:114:19)
at context.describe.context.context (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:44:27)
at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/test/credentials.spec.coffee:398:5)
at Object.create (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:114:19)
at context.describe.context.context (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:44:27)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/test/credentials.spec.coffee:362:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/test/credentials.spec.coffee:694:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.loadFile (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:182:19)
at Module.load (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:211:36)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at /Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:231:27
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:228:14)
at Mocha.run (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:514:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:480:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Theres a few things I'm not sure about here. Firstly, `return creds = new AWS.TemporaryCredentials({` does not exist on line 366. I think the error is actually referring to `creds = new AWS.TemporaryCredentials(DurationSeconds: 1200)` on line 370. I believe the coffeescript gets transpiled to JavaScript. Is it possible that the error message is line 366 of the JavaScript that gets generated?

Also, I'm not sure what to do to resolve this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error message is being given in javascript (as you can tell by the `return` keyword which isn't used in Coffeescript), and the line number is from a transpiled javascript version of the coffeescript file. You may be able to get better line numbers by using [sourcemaps](http://coffeescript.org/#source-maps), but I'm not familiar with using these with test libraries.

In this specific case, you are running tests for an npm package. Looking it up on [Github](https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-js), the missing constructor does in fact [not exist in the source code
outside of tests](https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=TemporaryCredentials&type=).

The package looks to be a fork of the AWS SDK and still uses some of the AWS methods internally. My guess is the code being tested was removed, but the tests weren't updated. Try contacting the package maintainers or opening an issue on Github.